# How to loop through the elements of a tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a function `batch_rot90(batch_of_images)` using TensorFlow's `tf.image.rot90()`, the latter only takes one image at a time, the former should take a batch of n images at once (shape = [n,x,y,f]).

So naturally, one should just itterate through all images in the batch and rotate them one by one. In numpy this would look like:

```
def batch_rot90(batch):
  for i in range(batch.shape[0]):
    batch_of_images[i] = rot90(batch[i,:,:,:])
  return batch
```

How is this done in TensorFlow?
using `tf.while_loop` I got his far:

```
batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 256, 256, 4])    
def batch_rot90(batch, k, name=''):
      i = tf.constant(0)
      def cond(batch, i):
        return tf.less(i, tf.shape(batch)[0])
      def body(im, i):
        batch[i] = tf.image.rot90(batch[i], k)
        i = tf.add(i, 1)
        return batch, i  
      r = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [batch, i])
      return r
```

But the assignment to `im[i]` is not allowed, and I'm confused about what is returned with r.

I realize there might be a workaround for this particular case using `tf.batch_to_space()` but I believe it should be possible with a loop of some kind too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated Answer:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 3])

def cond(batch, output, i):
    return tf.less(i, tf.shape(batch)[0])

def body(batch, output, i):
    output = output.write(i, tf.add(batch[i], 10))
    return batch, output, i + 1

# TensorArray is a data structure that support dynamic writing
output_ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,
               size=0,
               dynamic_size=True,
               element_shape=(x.get_shape()[1],))
_, output_op, _  = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [x, output_ta, 0])
output_op = output_op.stack()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output_op, feed_dict={x: [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]]}))
```

---

<s>I think you should consider using `tf.scatter_update` to update one image in the batch, instead of using `batch[i] = ...`. Refer to [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) for detail. In your case, I suggest change the first line of body to:</s>

```
tf.scatter_update(batch, i, tf.image.rot90(batch[i], k))
```

Comment: That doesn't work because `batch` is only a placeholder

Comment: I updated my answer, which still use `while_loop`. But I think your own solution is more elegant. +1 on that. P.S. I found that `map_fn` use `TensorArray` and `while_loop` internally.

Comment: Great for the more general case. It does make me wonder if this is any better than numpy, it is going to use double the memory,...

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I would like to think the immutable tensor manipulation as functional programming, which is inefficient to memory usage,  but may be efficient to parallel computing.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, I was looking for it for quite some time! In order to be easier to search for, should we extend the question title as: "How to loop through the elements of a tensor in TensorFlow and save intermediate results in a TensorArray?"

Answer (score 3):

There is a map function in tf, that will work:

```
def batch_rot90(batch, k, name=''):
  fun = lambda x: tf.images.rot90(x, k = 1)
  return = tf.map_fn(fun, batch)
```